# mysql insert a value by adding previous value

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a table named as *goal*, inside that there are two columns ID (primarykey autoincreement)
and amount(long int)

By default the long int value will be 0. Is it possible to update this row by adding amount in addition.

Initially its 0, if someone donated some amount, then the current amount would be updated by donated amount.

For eg.

Current Amount = 50(in database)

Amount Donated = 10

So after updating the row the amount should be 60.

I can do this by first selecting the amount and then updating it, but is there any alternative of this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can update it in-place.

```
update table
set amount = amount + 50
where id = your_id
```

Comment: only if you are a moderator, can I get a reason why I got down votes? Its a question nothing spam

Comment: No, I'm not a moderator. But I guess, you're getting downvoted for not putting enough effort into research. This is **really** basic stuff.

Comment: Don't take it personally, @ntechi   There's a whole bunch of people on stackoverflow who love nothing more than roaming around and putting -1 against anything that displeases them and feeling superior in the process. It is absolutely the worst thing about the site. Just ignore it :)

Comment: @Nick I am not taking it personally, but because of this negatives now I am not able to ask any more questions. The restricted me.

Comment: @ntechi: wait, it should wear off. In the meanwhile, go read a book and next time do your homework before asking (just a friendly advice :) ).

Comment: Really?! I'm sorry to hear that. Sergio is right, though; the restriction should only last for a set period, I believe.

Answer (score 4):

```
UPDATE `goal` SET `amount` = `amount` + 10 WHERE ID = 1
```

Comment: only if you are a moderator, can I get a reason why I got down votes? Its a question nothing spam